# Aggregation Mongodb with check each row data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

first of all,
i have tried different method in aggregation mongodb, but can't find what i want.

I have list of collection like this :

```
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '123', start_out : '111' },    
{'ids' : 2, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '523', start_out : '444' },    
{'ids' : 3, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '111', start_out : '456' },    
{'ids' : 4, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '124', start_out : '854' },    
{'ids' : 5, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '456', start_out : '987' },    
{'ids' : 6, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '987', start_out : '878' },
{'ids' : 7, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '434', start_out : '544' },
```

and with aggregation mongodb, I want a result list like this :

```
{'ids' : 1, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '123', start_out : '111' },    
{'ids' : 3, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '111', start_out : '456' },    
{'ids' : 5, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '456', start_out : '987' },    
{'ids' : 6, name : 'john', address : 'New Jerse', start_in : '987', start_out : '878' },
```

there is relation in start_out with start_in.

Is there any possibility to create a result like above with aggregation ?
I spend a lot of my time to try this, but still no result.

Comment: this could be achieved with graph search, but that is only available in Mongo 3.4, are you ok that?

Comment: thanks kang,

i have update to mongo 3.4, and it's really work.

until you answer that, i still don't know there is a new release mongo 3.4.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Mongo 3.4, this aggregation will do job:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            ids: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: 'collectionName',
            startWith: '$start_out',
            connectFromField: 'start_out',
            connectToField: 'start_in',
            as: 're'
        },
    }, {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $concatArrays: [[{
                    _id: '$_id',
                  ids: '$ids',
                  name: '$name',
                  address: '$address',
                  start_in: '$start_in',
                  start_out: '$start_out',
                }],{
                    $reverseArray: '$re',
                }]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

Comment: Thanks, 
but now i'm using mongo 3.2.

i will try to change mongo first.
But i appreciate your answer.

Thanks kang.